# To import Sass files, you first need to install node-sass

Tags: node.js, sass, create-react-app, node-sass

Running create-react-app, I get the error in my create-react-app application:

> To import Sass files, you first need to install node-sass. Run `npm
>   install node-sass` or `yarn add node-sass` inside your workspace.

I do have node-sass installed.

package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0"
  }
```

project node_modules folder:

[image]

I've uninstalled, reinstalled, updated, cleaned cache, etc.  How do I fix?

Comment: it should be on the dependencies and not on the devDependencies I think

Comment: @ocheriaf - I have other projects setup this way and it works

Comment: Are you calling node-sass from your package.json when you run your build? eg: `"build": "node-sass --other build steps"`

Comment: I am forking create-react-app, and was running npx create-react-app --scripts-version file:../my-local/react-scripts.  Then I would get this error in the created app.  I then published the react scripts to npm and ran it that way and no longer get this error.  don't understand that

Comment: Same problem here. Are you using Yarn workspaces by any chance?

Comment: @rnbrady - I am not

Answer (score 25):

In my case I had the same problem even though `node-sass` was already installed in my project directory.

> To import Sass files, you first need to install node-sass. Run npm
> install node-sass or yarn add node-sass inside your workspace.

What I figured out is, my project was running on the react scripts installed globally, and there was an another version inside my local project directory. There was a conflict in getting the base path of 'node-sass'.

I uninstalled the local react-scripts and installed it again in the local project directory. Run,

`npm uninstall react-scripts` then 
`npm install react-scripts`

That fixed my problem!

Comment: Reinstalling react-scripts helped! Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

what worked for me was that I uninstalled global node-sass
and installed it in my current project directory

```
npm uninstall -g node-sass

npm install node-sass
```

**make sure to stop npm start** until after installation, if possible restart your system when installation is done

Comment: `make sure to stop npm start until after installation` - The only thing I had to do.

Answer (score 4):

`node-sass` is deprecated, use `sass` instead. But sass loader expects `node-sass`. No problem, we can install `sass` and trick `sass-loader` that `sass` is a `node-sass`

Install `sass`

`npm install sass@^1.55.0 --save`

In your `package.json` file, replace `sass` entry with this. We can use `alias` names in package json

`node-sass": "npm:sass@^1.55.0`

example

```
"dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18.1",
        "moment": "^2.29.3",
        "node-sass": "npm:sass@^1.55.0",
        ...
```

works like a charm.

Comment: For some reason this solution is not working for me. I've just install sass and loader require node-sass. Can you have other solution for that?

Answer (score 2):

`node-sass` has been deprecated. Please install `sass` or dart sass to fix your issues.

Comment: Does create-react-app need to update their docs https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet/

Comment: Looks like they did. I tried to convert to sass, but now I'm getting an error on npm start that I need to install node-sass.

Comment: @J.Gwinner, I've run into the same issue as well. What I did was uninstall and install ```react-scripts```.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and setting the `SASS_PATH` environment variable fixed it for me.

For example if you use `docker-compose.yml` then add:

```
environment:
  - SASS_PATH=node_modules:src
```

Maybe someone else can explain why this was needed.

Answer (score 1):

In my case below was my error,

```
./src/modules/TestListing/components/SurveyCard/index.scss 

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-4!

./src/modules/TestListing/components/SurveyCard/index.scss)


To import Sass files, you first need to install node-sass.
Run `npm install node-sass` or `yarn add node-sass` inside your workspace.
```

The error was happening even though I had installed `node-sass` globally which was weird.

I figured `react-scripts` could not able to recognize `node-sass` in it's environment , Hence I have added node-sass dependency in globally installed `react-scripts` package

```
cd /usr/local/bin/node_modules/react-scripts
sudo npm install --unsafe-perm node-sass
```

In the above command I am actually installing node-sass to a react-script package which is a library, It could fix the issue in my case,

Becareful on the commands, Because I am dong `--unsafe-perm`, Read it before you do

---

Answer (score 0):

Actually what worked for me was creating a new folder, creating a react app from there and transferring all the codes to that new folder. Not sure why the problem occurred in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and I noticed that `npm install node-sass` was breaking before full installation. I also tried `npm uninstall -g node-sass` which wasn't adding the package to the package.json file. What worked for me is `npm install node-sass --save` which installed node--sass and added it as a dev dependency to my package.json file

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I figured out it by installing sass moduele.

> npm install sass

or

> yarn add sass

Answer (score -3):

Generally, you should install `node-sass`:

```
npm install node-sass --save
# or
yarn add node-sass
```

**How to import**

```
@import 'styles/_colors.scss'; // assuming a styles directory under src/
@import '~nprogress/nprogress'; // importing a css file from the nprogress node module
```

**Sass path variable**

> To use imports relative to a path you specify, and from `node_modules` without adding the `~` prefix, you can add a `.env` [file](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/docusaurus/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables.md#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env) at the project root with the variable `SASS_PATH=node_modules:src`. To specify more directories you can add them to `SASS_PATH` separated by a `:` like `path1:path2:path3`.